# Salami and Cheese -- pun on a greeting formula

Tags: greeting, puns

Somebody once told me about this pun. What is it, and what's the original formula?

PS: A preliminary web search only finds food blogs, and I don't know at the moment how to refine the search. Grazie mille.

PS: I was told bye bye in a chat room by an Italian over half a decade ago with a pun in the Italian equivalent of "salami and cheese", that was explained as a rhyme on a common greeting. I'm sure about the salami, but not the cheese. I don't know why I hadn't made the connection to Arabic "salamu", indeed it seems plausible, but there were no clues about cultural background; the guy identified chiefly Italian in my mind, at least with regards to cuisine --also taught me a genuine carbonara receipe without creme. Looking up "cheese" now, *cacio* for *ciao* seems more likely than *formaggio*.

I thought both phrases were common.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @vectory! I don't understand your question. Could you please add some more details?

Comment: I think this is an English language question rather than an Italian one. Probably a pun on Arabic greeting “salam” https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salam

Comment: @Charo, I was told bye bye in a chat room by an italian over half a decade ago with a pun in the italian equivalent of "salami and cheese", that was explained as a rhyme on a common greeting. I'm sure about the salami, but not the cheese. I don't know why I hadn't made the connection to Arabic "salamu", indeed it seems plausible, but there were no clues about cultural background; the guy identified chiefly italian in my mind, at least with regards to cuisine--also taught me a genuine carbonara receipe without creme. Looking up "cheese" now, *cacio* for *ciao* seems more likely than *formaggio*

Comment: shout out to DalaiLamer on #warsow.pickup@quakenet irc! what are you up to these days?

Comment: No reference to Arabic here. It should be something about _saluti_ (greetings), which is similar to _salumi_ (salami and other such specialties). Perhaps, _salumi e formaggi_ (rather than, say, _saluti e omaggi_)?

Comment: @DaG: Quello che hai detto appare in  [questo forum](https://mmamania.it/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4911&start=60).

Comment: @DaG:    Immagino che Jacovitti sia il [fumettista](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benito_Jacovitti). Siccome aveva fatto molti fumetti con i salami, può darsi che abbia inventato questo gioco di parole, "salumi e formaggi".

Comment: Sorry, in English. An entry in [this forum](https://mmamania.it/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4911&start=60) seems to suggest that "salumi e formaggi" may be a pun said by Italian comic artist [Benito Jacovitti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benito_Jacovitti). If you look for "salami Jacovitti" at Google, you will see lots of salami drawn by Jacovitti  in his comics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be *Saluti e baci* -> *Salumi e caci*. A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22salumi%20e%20caci%22) turns up a few examples of this pun, mixed with the literal use of these words.

Comment: I can't see any example in this Google search in which "salumi e caci" is used to say goodbye or as a greeting formula.

Comment: @Charo I have this one on page 2, for instance: https://www.corriere.it/solferino/severgnini/04-06-24/03.spm, and then http://www.quarei.it/matonele/?p=5758 and https://amcastelfusano.forumattivo.com/t189-maledette-queste-ripetute .

Comment: Yes, that's true, @FedericoPoloni, now I've found other instances.